# Check nullity of a file path - best practices

Tags: java, file, null

I'm currently a technical dillema. I'm getting path of certain files from a resource bundle in my app. It's a key-value system.

If my "file-path" key return null value. Should i check the nullity or let my Files or FileUtils API handle in the normal process?

```
public class FileTest {

        public save() {
              String path = bundle.getValue("path.key");
              // first option (i find it ugly)
              if(path == null) {
                   new Exception();
              }
              // Option 2
              // Should i check nullity from the key or continue 
              // the process and let the APIs handle the null as illegal argument ?
              try {
                Files.createDirectory(path);
              }catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();              
              }
         }
}
```

Any opinions ?

Comment: Check if `null` or handle possible `Exception`s, your choice, I think...

Comment: Hi, because there is nothing wrong with your code and you are mostly asking for best practice, you should to put your question to [codereview stackexchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com), you can expect only closing there, because question is too broad. Please, if you will do, delete the post from stackoverflow to avoid cross-domain posting, thanks in advance.

Comment: From my point of view, personally, if returning null is kind of normal behavior, then to add null check will be good I think, if it's something not usual, then probably handle exception is kind of more proper way how to deal with it.

Comment: Personally, I like to think only by block, and to create stupid-proof code. In your case, the first block is getting the path. If it can return null, and it's a non wanted result, then add an `if-null` instruction to manage the case. Second block (don't know your case but may be much later on the code than where you get the path value). I ignore the part where I get the path and write it to manage every case, so with a try catch. May produce heavy and redundant code, but it's really useful when you work on team, and don't have the hand on all the code

Comment: @xxxvodnikxxx this is not suitable for codereview because this is not real code. (Hypothetical scenario code is not accepted.) If OP can include current working code of their application it can be reviewed.

Comment: @422_unprocessable_entity I dont think its not a real code, ok, its not complete code and only kind of snippet, but its a real .. 
anyway, you are correct its not right example of post which you fit to C.Rev.